# How to open ssh gcloud vm session from the browser to another account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I have a VM instance setup in Google Cloud. Most of the time I use `gcloud` tool to open ssh session from the terminal, it uses a user account on the VM with the same name as the account I am connecting from.

When, however, I open an SSH session from the browser it uses another user account on the VM, the one with the same name as the email I use to login to google cloud from the browser.

I would like to open the session from the browser and to log into the another account of my choice, the one I open from the terminal for instance.

How can I manage that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all responses, Nick and Lin. Actually, I have just found what I was looking for: after I open ssh session in my browser window, in its upper right corner the 'cog' settings allow me to "Change Linux Username". With that I was able to switch.

Answer (score 1):

After ssh into your virtual machine from the browser, you can login with another account by using the command [`$ gcloud auth login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login)

You will get a link that allows you to choose a different account. After choosing the account, you will get a verification code. Paste the verification code into the VM instance terminal and you are done.

To verify the change, you can use [`$ gcloud auth list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list) to see the accounts you currently have available. You should see a `*` sign before the **current active account**.

Now you can also set the active account by running:
    `$ gcloud config set account [YOUR_ACCOUNT]`

**Extra**: In case you want to use a different account from the terminal, you can simply use  [`$ gcloud compute ssh [user@]INSTANCE`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Chrome, click the three-dot menu in the upper right corner and from the menu that drops down click "New incognito window". Then use the incognito window to connect to the Google Cloud console. Using incognito mode prevents the browser from reading your cookies, so it allows you to log in with a different account than the one you're logged into in the standard browser window.

If you're not using Chrome, pretty much all the major browsers offer an equivalent. Firefox also calls it "Incognito". IE and Edge call it "InPrivate".